# remove double extensions in bash

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I am familiar with rename but I was curious does rename still apply for removing duplicate extensions??

Say I have a few files named:

- picture2.jpg.jpg
- picture9.jpg.jpg
- picture3.jpg.jpg
- picture6.jpg.jpg

How would you remove the the duplicate extension??

End result:

- picture2.jpg
- picture9.jpg
- picture3.jpg
- picture6.jpg

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming:

- You only want to perform this in the current working directory (non-recursively)
- The double extensions have format precisely as `.jpg.jpg`:

Then the following script will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.jpg.jpg
do
    mv "${file}" "${file%.jpg}"
done
```

**Explanation:**

- `${file%.jpg}`: This part is called [Parameter Subsitution.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)
- From the same source: *"${var%Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var."*
- Note that the "pattern" mentioned here is called globbing, which is [different from regular expression in important ways](http://lwn.net/Articles/96687/).

**To use this script:**

- Create a new file called `clean_de.sh` in that directory
- Set it to executable by `chmod +x clean_de.sh`
- Then run it by `./clean_de.sh`

---

**A Note of Warning**:

As @gniourf_gniourf have pointed out, use the `-n` option if your `mv` supports it.

Otherwise - if you have `a.jpg` and `a.jpg.jpg` in the same directory, it will rename `a.jpg.jpg` to `a.jpg` and in the process override the already existing `a.jpg` without warning.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed thank you.  I would assume is the %\ doing the change?

Comment: If your `mv` has the `-n` option (no clobber option), you can use it, just to be safe in case the target file already exists.

Answer (score 5):

One line rename command should also suffice (for your case at least):

```
rename 's/\.jpg\.jpg$/.jpg/' *.jpg.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general, but still easy solution for this problem:

```
for oldName in `find . -name "*.*.*"`; do newName=`echo $oldName | rev | cut -f2- -d'.' | rev`; mv $oldName $newName; done
```

Short explanation:
`find . -name "*.*.*` - this will find only the files with duplicate extensions recursively

`echo $oldName | rev | cut -f2- -d'.' | rev` - the trick happens here: the rev command do a reverse on the string, so you now you can see, that you want the whole filename from the first dot. (gpj.gpj.fdsa)

`mv $oldName $newName` - to actually rename the files

*Release Notes: since it is a simple one-line script, you can find unhandled cases. Files with an extra dot in the filename, super-deep directory structures, etc.*

Comment: This will clobber a similar-named non-double-suffix file. If the directory contains image.jpg.php and image.jpg.jpg, the first file will be deleted.